# Gradle is not setting Eclipse's .classpath correctly with Java 9+

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradle-plugin

Up to Java 8 Gradle and Eclipse seem to enjoy each other, starting with Java 9 it becomes messy. I've configured the eclipse plugin in gradle as specified in the documentation (no version or anything)
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html

But this does not set the source and target compatibility correctly, nor the JRE to use. So I have added this to my gradle.build:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-9/' // Add correct container
        file {
            whenMerged { classpath ->
                classpath.entries.removeAll { entry -> entry.kind == 'con' && !entry.path.contains('JavaSE-9')} // Remove all other containers
                classpath.entries.findAll{ it.kind == 'src' && it.entryAttributes['gradle_used_by_scope'].equals('test') }.each { // Mark test folders as containing test sourcers
                    it.entryAttributes['test'] = 'true'
                }
            }
        }
   }
   jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9 
        targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
   }
}
```

This works, but the lingering question of course is: why do I need to do this? I really can't imagine Gradle's eclipse plugin is lagging so much it would not support Java 9.

Anyhow, having fixed that, there is one thing remaining that I cannot fix: if I print the classpath in the whenMerged I see ProjectDependency and Library entries, in the resulting .classpath file these are missing. The result .classpath only contains the Source and Container entries. How come?

My project uses Gradle 4.9 and Eclipse 2018-09. Eclipse is setup to use the Gradle wrapper (but using 4.10.3 does not make a difference).

Comment: Executing this from the command line, generates the correct .classpath: gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse

Comment: The Java version can be set outside of `eclipse { ... }` via `sourceCompatibility = ...` ([as you can see in my video here](https://youtu.be/uJNzMGrbXbI?t=155)). For test class separation the following snippet works for me: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4802#issuecomment-396165166 By the way, the current version is Eclipse 2018-12 which contains Buildship 3.0. Please upgrade.

Comment: The source compatibility is already set correctly, the gradle build runs fully from the command line, eclipse is not picking it up and I have to explicitly set it in the jdt block. When executing 'eclipse' from the command line, the project entries containing modules are not marked as "exports one or more modules" in eclipse. I'll upgrade Eclipse when eclipse.org is back online.

Comment: What do you mean by "project entries containing modules"? What kind of modules? JPMS modules?

Comment: This is about Java 9+, so jigsaw, aka module-info.java. That information is supposed to be picked up and used to configure the eclipse project dependency, by specifying that such a dependency "exports one or more modules".

Comment: Java 9+ does not force you to use JPMS alias Jigsaw. One Eclipse Java project cannot contain multiple modules (`module-info.java` files) as each module has its own dependencies. Could you please show your project structure?

Comment: I know, but I am exporting several modules. As said, the project is compiling just fine, it's the eclipse integration that goes wrong with J9+ https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras

Comment: The Eclipse Gradle integration works for me (also in Java 9, 10 and 11) so I wonder what's going wrong in your particular case.

Comment: So am I. :-) The build.gradle file is not completely of my making, I don't understand Gradle well enough (out side the basic usage), so other people made the changes that were needed to get asciidoc etc working. I can see that conflicting with generating the Eclipse files. Thanks for trying!